# Layout Android off-screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I built this layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffeecc"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="a.activity.YearActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"

        android:text="@string/pikerTitleStart"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#FF4500"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/datePicker1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/datePicker1"

        android:text="@string/pikerTitleEnd"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#FF4500"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/datePicker2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The code works correctly when the screen is vertical. But when I turn the screen DatePiker the lower leaves off the screen.
I'm freaking out should be simple.

How can I set it to stay inside the screen? Thanks.

**How can I set it to stay inside the screen?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your layout inside a scrollview

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

Check this sample application for details:
http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/scrollview/android-scrollview-example/